# How to do an in-place upgrade of SQL Server 2005 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to upgrade my SQL Server 2005 Express instance which is installed using this command:

```
SQLEXPR.EXE/qs /action=INSTALL /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 
   /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=ABCD
   /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SECURITYMODE=SQL
   /SAPWD=abc#Wd1234 /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1
```

but when I am trying to upgrade the server instance `ABCD` with this command

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /q /ACTION=upgrade /INSTANCENAME=ABCD /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1
```

the instance `ABCD` is not upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

When I check ADD/Remove program list of OS, it shows me both SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2 are installed (that may be I am doing a side by side upgrade but not a in-place one) and when I click on start button of OS and then goes to SQL Server 2008 R2 folder in `AllPrograms` list. It has a sub folder configuration tools which contains SQL Server Installation center. When I open the installation center it show various option to install SQL Server 2008 R2 or to upgrade from 2005 etc. I am confused whether SQL Server 2008 R2 is even installed on my machine after running the above 2nd query. Please help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the 2005 instance is 64-bit? What happens if, instead of the command line, you run setup through the UI, and select the upgrade option? Maybe you'll get better information about what's going wrong...

Comment: when i used the query select @@Version it gives result as Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86) 
 Dec 10 2010 10:56:29 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1 .so it might be 32-bit instance but what i am not able to understand is that my machine is windows 7 64 bit and i am installing sql server 2005 express edition 64 bit installer then why is it making a 32-bit instance ??

Answer (score 2):

You have a 32-bit instance of SQL Server 2005 and are trying to upgrade to a 64-bit instance of a newer version. This is not supported; you can check any of the upgrade documents about this, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393(v=sql.105).aspx:

> Cross-platform upgrade is not supported. You cannot upgrade a 32-bit instance of SQL Server to native 64-bit.

It says stuff about WOW64 but my recommendation for your scenario is to install a separate 2008 R2 instance, backup/restore your databases from the 2005 instance (and transfer jobs/logins), then remove that instance. You will need to choose a different instance name or use a default instance.